# c# Generic cannot convert source type to target type

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I use the Repository pattern in my project. Every component has a Bll class.

I want to create a base bll class, the sub Bll class can work without the same Repository  Curd method.

### But It appears the "Cannot convert ..DriverRepository to target type ...Repository IEntity>"

**language:c#**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class , IEntity
{

    protected string ConnectionStringName;
    protected IDatabase Db;

    public Repository(string connStringName)
    {
        ConnectionStringName = connStringName;
        Db = new Database(ConnectionStringName);
    }
    public Repository()
    {
        ConnectionStringName = "DefaultConnection";
        Db = new Database(ConnectionStringName);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseBll
{
    protected Repository<IEntity> DefaultRepository;

    protected BaseBll(Repository<IEntity> repository)
    {
        _defaultRepository = repository;
    }    
    protected virtual List<IEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DefaultRepository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class DriverRepository : Repository<Driver>
{
    public Driver GetDriverByLicenseNumber(string licenseNumber)
    {
        return Db.SingleOrDefault<Driver>("where LicenseNumber = @0", licenseNumber);
    }
}

public class DriverBll
{
    public DriverBll()
    {
        DefaultRepository = new DriverRepository();
        //***Throw the Cannot convert ... to ... Error. Why?****
    }
}
```

But...

Comment: What is `MyRepository`?

Comment: create a constructor in DriverRepo,  pass connection string and call base constructor passing connection string?

Comment: I see "protected  MyRepository DefaultRepository;". Can you post the MyRepository class code ?

Comment: Sorry about the MyRepository . It's just a test. whatever I use it or not,The Cannot Convert is exist.

Comment: Although it is not the case in your code, I guess that DriverBll must inherit from BaseBll. Then, you have to ensure that the Driver class inherits from IEntity. Is it the case ?

Comment: Yes,The driver class inherits from IEntity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no zero-parameter constructor in `Repository`, but `DriverRepository` inherits from it. Because you have no zero-parameter constructor in `Repository`, when `DriverRepository` tries to create itself, it has no constructor to call on `Repository`. You need to invoke the `Repository(connectionString)` constructor from `DriverRepository`'s constructor like so.

```
public DriverRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
public DriverRepository() : base("YourConnectionString")
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Upon clarification.
Firstly in this code example, `DriverBll` does not extend from `BaseBll`, so it doesnt' know about the `DefaultRepository` property. Secondly, `Driver` must be implementing `IEntity`.

Comment: Sorry ,I forget to copy that constructor:

Comment: `code` public Repository()
  {
   ConnectionStringName = "DefaultConnection";
   Db = new Database(ConnectionStringName);
  }

Comment: In which case, we need your MyRepository class to proceed further.

Comment: Sorry about the MyRepository~

Comment: Concerning the EDIT: That won't help either, as a `Repository<Driver>` simply is not assignment-compatible to `Repository<IEntity>` unless generic co-/contravariance is used, even if `Driver` implements `IEntity`.

Comment: That was assuming IEntity was meant to be a generic type on the class ie `Repository<IEntity> where IEntity : class;`